# Complex relational configuration in yaml and symfony

Tags: symfony, configuration, yaml

I would like to create complex configuration, where some of configs relies on another. Let's give a simple example:

```
item_parameters:
    sample_parameter_1:
        name: 'Test 1'
        type: 'ABC'
    sample_parameter_2:
        name: 'Test 2'
        type: 'XYZ'
    sample_parameter_3:
        name: 'Test 3'
        type: 'ABC'
items:
    sample_item_1:
        name: 'Test item 1'
        parameters:
            - %item_parameters.sample_parameter_1%
            - %item_parameters.sample_parameter_3%
    sample_item_2:
        name: 'Test item 2'
        parameters:
            - %item_parameters.sample_parameter_2%
            - %item_parameters.sample_parameter_3%
```

The problem is, that I cannot point to %item_parameters.sample_parameter_1% etc, because I cannot access array elements defined in yml. Is it possible to make it work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you'r talking at the config not the parameters and to do that you need to setup a configuration tree see the docs here:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/config/definition.html

Comment: Thx, you are right, with configurations I can assign element of config array into another config, but for my needs it would require too much work, I think I'll stay with parameters, its way faster to do, and just pass parameter name into item parameters array, like - 'sample_parameter_1', and then read its value inside service that will handle those configs.